# Syn data when internet is available

Tags: android, android-room, syn

My user will be collecting data where internet is not available so I want to syn as soon as user comes under internet availability. What is the best approach to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Service in the background for Sync the data for USER.

Comment: Don't you think so that using a work manager is better to approach?